# Templates for SharePoint 2019 on premises

Tags: modern-experience, site-collection, sharepoint-on-prem, site-template, 2019

Is there a way to use Microsoft pre-built templates in SharePoint on-premises?

Pre built meaning the ones that SharePoint 365 has per this link:
[Apply and customize SharePoint site templates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-and-customize-sharepoint-site-templates-39382463-0e45-4d1b-be27-0e96aeec8398#ID0EDBJ=Team_site_templates)

Comment: "pre-built templates"?

Comment: Yes, like the templates that are available in sharepoint 365.

Comment: As per the documentation templates should be supported in *`SharePoint Server Subscription Edition, SharePoint Server 2019, and SharePoint in Microsoft 365`*.

Answer (score 0):

The 2019 reference is misleading. These templates are only available to online. One more effort to push us away from using on-premise (ala Subscription). Seems you can't buy anything anymore, you have to subscribe and pay, and pay, and pay.